# What does it take to be a researcher/professor at a top, top university?

Tags: phd, professorship, university

I'm just an undergrad, so I'm not really asking this question for myself. This comes more from general curiosity. I know/know of several people who did PhDs from top universities (e.g. Princeton, MIT, Berkeley, etc) but could not go on to be hired by top universities. Many were hired by good and well known universities (e.g. University of Toronto or Haverford College), but not by the absolute cream of the crop.

Based on this, I wonder what it is that qualifies or differentiates someone to research and teach at the very finest universities (I'm thinking Harvard, Princeton, MIT, etc). What's the difference between Princeton PhDs who teach at Princeton/Harvard/etc and Princeton PhDs who teach at Haverford (again, no offence to Haverford - it's an excellent institution - just using it as an example of a school that's good but not quite up there with the New England schools and the likes)? Is it because the former have just engaged in far superior research (and write far better dissertations), or that they have been able to "network" more effectively in the academic community, or something else? What role does luck have to play, if any?

Comment: Here's a very similar (but perhaps unfortunately named) question: [What does it take to get a tenure track position at an Ivy League School?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1753/17254) I particularly like the point made in Anonymous Mathematician's answer about the numerical guarantee.

Comment: _... so I’m not really asking this question for myself._ “Asking for a friend”? ;-)

Comment: @DanRomik No. What I mean by not asking the question for myself is that I'm not even close to thinking about thinking about post-phd academia jobs, and so whatever answers I get here don't have any bearing on anything I do in my life (if I do decide to enter academia at some point in my life, I will surely not remember this thread so many years into the future). A genuine question out of curiosity based on something I've observed.

Comment: Also, can the downvotes explain? I don't see a reason to downvote a perfectly valid question, based on an observation which people do generally seem to agree with.

Comment: @gtoques no worries, it was a joke. I wouldn’t think poorly of you either way, whether you are asking for yourself, for a friend, out of curiosity or for any other reason.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but can see why people would think this not a good for for Academia.SE. What kind of answer would you consider "correct"? How would you objectively differentiate "superior research" from "networking"? What data are you expecting to see in response? Without objective data, this becomes a "primarily opinion-based" question, which is a reason for closing.

Comment: Yes the question is way too broad. It is like asking what makes a good son, a good ____ (insert profession). Too many qualities, across a board. A discussion about the selection criterias is more concrete and specific. It is also somewhat offensive, comparing different colleges as better and less than. Many very accomplished Ivy League professors prefer the smaller institutions due to the increased freedom and being able to connect with different communities as part of their work. Implying somesort of gradient denigrates this.

Comment: I think this is answered by Anonymous Mathematician's answer in the question linked by Anyon.

Comment: @Poidah, I have clearly mentioned that the places I refer to as "less than" (in your words) are just taken as examples of schools that are very good at what they do, but not considered to be at the level of Princeton, Harvard, etc. I completely understand that people might prefer smaller schools to bigger ones, but I don't think any argument can be made for the kind of schools I have referred to being "better" (or more competitive to get hired at) than top ivies and the likes. That's all I mean.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing it takes to get hired at any place of employment: convincing the people at that institution that you’re a good fit for their organisation’s culture and strategic goals.